# How can I play an mp4 resource with AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, avplayer, avasset

I have included an mp4 resource in my project navigator. I want to play it in an AVPlayer. I know how to create an AVPlayerItem for the AVPlayer object, and so now I'd like to load the appropriate AVAsset into it pointing to my mp4 resource. The problem is that AVAsset only has an assetWithURL: method to create an AVAsset. I want an assetWithName: method, but that method does not exist. How can I play my mp4 file if I don't have a URL for it? If it's not possible to play via name reference, how can I get a file URL for my mp4 file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the URL, use

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"my_video" withExtension:@"mp4"]
```

Comment: Don't forget to select "Target Membership" in the right hand panel. Without that it didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

It will probably be in your main bundle, you can get its URL with

```
- (NSString*) saveFilePath: (NSString *) add
{
    NSString *filename = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:add ofType:@"mp4"]isDirectory:NO]]];
    return filename;
}
```

Copy this into your code and then do `[self saveFilePath:@"Name of your file"]` to get the URL.

Full code:

```
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[self saveFilePath:@"fileName"];
[player play];
```

Comment: Oops I missed that you weren't generating the file to your documents... I was just answering a recording question and I got confused. Anyway, I fixed the `saveFilePath` code so it should work now. I don't normally say this, but thanks to whoever downvoted.